# How I get center of points?

Tags: c++

Problem: Create a vector consisting of point objects in a two-dimensional plane, calculate the average of the x and y coordinates of the point objects, and write a program that outputs the center of the points.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Point 
{
    public:

        Point(std::string pname = NULL, int px = 0, int py = 0)

        {
            setName(pname); setX(px); setY(py);
        }

        std::string getName() { return name; }

        int getX() { return x; }

        int getY() { return y; }

        void setName(std::string pname) { name = pname; }

        void setX(int px) { x = px; }

        void setY(int py) { y = py; }

    private:

        std::string name;

        int x;

        int y;

};

int main()
{
    int a;
    int counter = 0;
    cout << "number of points" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    vector<Point> v1(a);
    while (counter < a)
    {
        Point p1;

        string tmp;
        int tmp_x;
        int tmp_y;

        cout << "name of point" << endl;
        cin >> tmp;
        p1.setName(tmp);
        
        cout << "position of point" << endl;
        cin >> tmp_x >> tmp_y;
        p1.setX(tmp_x);
        p1.setY(tmp_y);

        v1.push_back(p1);
        cout << p1.getName() <<p1.getX() << p1.getY() << endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this is an example of what I want (inline is keyboard input)

Number of points: `2`

Name of point: `p1`
position of a point: `10 20`
p1 (10, 20)

Name of point: `p2`
position of a point: `40 50`
p2 (40, 50)

centor of points :(25.0, 35.0)

How should I approach averaging?

Comment: If you had this as a pen-and-paper exercise, how would you do it then?

Comment: By the way, I suggest you take some time to explain your loop `while (counter < a)` to a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Especially explain in detail when and how the loop will end.

Comment: How about you get the existing program to work, correctly? You are making a very common mistake of attempting to write a huge pile of code first and only then figure out whether it works or not.  If you actually tried to execute the shown code you would discover that it is already broken and doesn't work. If your intent when running it, for example, was to enter three points, after three points the shown code continues to ask you to enter more points, which is clearly wrong. You should fix all problems with the existing code first, before moving onto the next step.

Comment: Just my two cents: the average of x and y coordinates doesn't necessarily form the center of points (or it depends how you define "center"). If the center shall be used to draw the smallest possible circle around all the points then the average of x/y coordinates is clearly not the solution. (This is easy to proof with multiple points with identical coordinates except one with different.)

Comment: I stumbled over this when I once was looking for a fast approach to find the perfect (i.e. minimal) bounding sphere (in 3d) for an arbitrary set of points (in 2d - the bounding circle but that doesn't change much), and I was surprised how hard it is, especially while trying to keep the time complexity close to O(n).

Comment: FYI: [Smallest-circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem)

Comment: If the actual question is just _how should I approach averaging_, then almost none of the code is relevant, and the answer is _by adding up N values and then dividing by N_, same as any other arithmetic mean. Since the simple arithmetic mean of the x values and the y values gives the right answer, presumably that's what is required.

Comment: `std::string pname = NULL` is not really correct. The symbol `NULL` is a C-compatible macro for null *pointers*. The `NULL` symbol shouldn't really be used in C++ programs at all. If you want an empty string as default-value then use an actual empty string. As in `std::string pname = ""`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need all of those `#include`s.
2. Pay attention to `NULL` in class constructor.
3. Loop continuation condition: `a--`. Variable `counter` is redundant.
4. Vector is dynamic data structure. You don't need to declare its size explicitly, in this exercise. Member-function `push_back` will do dirty work for you.
5. One more extra variable `p1`. Try:

   ```
   v1.push_back( { tmp, tmp_x, tmp_y } );
   ```
6. Finally...

   ```
   double // if precision is necessary
      total_x{}, total_y{};

   for ( auto& point : v1 ) {
      total_x += point.getX();
      total_y += point.getY();
   }

   std::cout << "Average X: " << total_x / v1.size()
           << "\nAverage Y: " << total_y / v1.size();

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   ```